# How do i update an edited record of a registered User in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Im  trying to update a registered user below is the error im getting

TypeError
App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::update(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, string given, called in C:\Users\pC\Documents\GitHub\PMI\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54**/

**Below is the code in my Controller to update user details**

```php
  protected function update(array $data, $id)
    {




        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        ([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'cellno' => $data['cellno'],
            'workno' => $data['workno'],
            'address' => $data['address'],

            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        ]);

        if (request()->hasFile('payslip')) {
            $file = request()->file('payslip');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('payslip/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->payslip = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('id_image')) {
            $file = request()->file('id_image');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('id_image/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->id_image = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('proof_of_res')) {
            $file = request()->file('proof_of_res');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('proof_of_res/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->proof_of_res = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

**If you can provide a Better code that'll be okay too...i just want to update records**

Comment: why are you expecting an array, that you are calling `$data`, as an argument to that method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is it expects an array of values in the URL itself.so you need to get all your data from the request() object

You need to add a route for this update as /user/{user}

```
protected function update(User $user )
    {
        $data = request()->all();

        $user = $user->fill([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'cellno' => $data['cellno'],
            'workno' => $data['workno'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        ]);
        
        //use form request for this validations
        //if (request()->hasFile('payslip')) {

            $file = request()->file('payslip');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('payslip/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->payslip = $filename;

       // }

        //if (request()->hasFile('id_image')) {
            $file = request()->file('id_image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('id_image/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->id_image = $filename;

       // }

        //if (request()->hasFile('proof_of_res')) {

            $file = request()->file('proof_of_res');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('proof_of_res/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->proof_of_res = $filename;
          
        //}

         $user->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

Comment: commented code works and there are some code practices u can do in there,for example you need to save user everytime.$user->save() used 4 times,file check can done in validators  and you can use model injection in routing itself

Answer (score 0):

*This Code worked for me which also allows for multiple image update*

```php
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'workno' => 'required',
            'cellno' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',

        ]);

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->cellno = $request->input('cellno');
        $user->workno = $request->input('workno');
        $user->address = $request->input('address');

        if (request()->hasFile('payslip')) {
            $file = request()->file('payslip');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('payslip/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->payslip = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('id_image')) {
            $file = request()->file('id_image');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('id_image/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->id_image = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        if (request()->hasFile('proof_of_res')) {
            $file = request()->file('proof_of_res');
            //            dd($file);
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $user->name . $user->email . '_' . $user->id . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('proof_of_res/' . $user->id . '/', $filename);
            $user->proof_of_res = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        $user->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It depend on how you are calling the function

App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::update([
'name' => 'Test',
....
]);

Then it will not give you an error.  If you are calling from route then it should be.

App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::update($request->all());